# How to create friendly URLs in Liferay

Tags: jsf, liferay, friendly-url

I am unable to shorten the URL of bookmarks present in bookmark module provided by Liferay DXP 7.0. I have tried by referring through [this article](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017880652-Making-URLs-Friendlier), but it doesn't seem to work.

According to liferay url friendly article that i had mentioned above I did create Route.xml and also did the configuration in liferay-portlet.xml. But still bookmarks that are created in bookmark portlet their url is not changed. I am attaching the routes.xml file and liferay-portlet.xml
Routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE routes PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Friendly URL Routes 7.0.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-friendly-url-routes_7_0_0.dtd">

<routes>
 <route>
  <pattern>/{Bookmark}</pattern>
  
  <implicit-parameter name="p_p_id">BookmarksPortlet</implicit-parameter>
  <implicit-parameter name="p_p_lifecycle">1</implicit-parameter>
  <implicit-parameter name="p_p_state">normal</implicit-parameter>
  <implicit-parameter name="p_p_mode">view</implicit-parameter>
  <implicit-parameter name="action">view</implicit-parameter>
 </route>
</routes>
```

Liferay-portlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE liferay-portlet-app PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Portlet Application 7.0.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-portlet-app_7_0_0.dtd">

<liferay-portlet-app>
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>BookmarksPortlet</portlet-name>
        <icon>/resources/images/icon.png</icon>
        
        <friendly-url-mapper-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.DefaultFriendlyURLMapper
        </friendly-url-mapper-class>
         <friendly-url-mapping>bookmarks-portlet</friendly-url-mapping>
         <friendly-url-routes>META-INF/friendly-url-routes/routes.xml</friendly-url-routes>
        
        <instanceable>true</instanceable>
        <requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
        <ajaxable>false</ajaxable>
        <css-class-wrapper>bookmarks-portlet</css-class-wrapper>
    </portlet>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        <role-link>Administrator</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>guest</role-name>
        <role-link>Guest</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>power-user</role-name>
        <role-link>Power User</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
        <role-link>User</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
</liferay-portlet-app>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and make this question a complete question with all information. See [ask]: On stackoverflow we prefer to have the questions self-contained because external content might go away. Plus, you're effectively asking us to guess what "doesn't seem to work" means and debug documentation. "Works for me" would probably not be a helpful answer.

Comment: Sorry for not writting it correctly.I have made changes . So please have a look and let me know where have i gone wrong